# How to create a Windows Service from .vbs file?

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-services, wsh

I have a .vbs file which I execute using **cscript**. Now that the script is sable; I want to run in background all the time.

Hence, I want this .vbs file to run as a service.

How do I create (install) it?

Answer (score 4):

Scripts are usually not prepared to run as a service (they don't provide the interfaces required for managing the service). You're probably better off creating a scheduled task that launches your script at system boot (or at logon).

```
schtasks /create /sc onstart /tn "name" /tr "cscript.exe C:\path\to\your.vbs" /ru SYSTEM
```